# How to get ID from duplicate values in another column

Tags: mysql

Sorry. I'm very new for MySQL Database. And, I have a problem.

I have a Table.

[image]

And I want to select ID that have Tag="XX" and Number = 13 and 17.

But If I query by this

```
SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE ( Tag="XX" and Number = 13 ) and ( Tag="XX" and Number = 17 )
```

I got nothing result.

and when I use this.

```
SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE ( Tag="XX" and Number = 13 ) or ( Tag="XX" and Number = 17 )
```

I get the result "A" and "B". But I want just "A" becuase "A" have tag "XX" with number 13 and 17 at the same time but "B" has tag "XX" with number 13 and 16

How do I need to do for select the ID from this condition.

Comment: Just read that query again - you try to fetch all rows where **all conditions** match

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve that. One is:

```
SELECT ID
FROM MyTable
WHERE Tag = "XX" AND Number IN (13, 17)
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Number) = 2
```

If the combination of (ID, Tag, Number) is UNIQUE, then you can also replace the HAVING clause with

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Another way is to use a JOIN:

```
SELECT t1.ID
FROM MyTable t1
JOIN MyTable t1 USING(ID)
WHERE t1.Tag = "XX" AND t1.Number = 13
  AND t2.Tag = "XX" AND t2.Number = 17
```

Comment: thank you very much. But If I have a lot of tag's name and number to match such as tag "XX" with number 13,17 **AND** tag "YY" with number 12,15 **AND** tag "ZZ" with number 14,15. Is there more easy way to achieve it.

Comment: @Sun - This answers your original question. If you have another question, post it as **another** question.

Answer (score 1):

Use below query to get your desired result.

```
select id from table a where tag='XX' and number=13 
and exists(select id from table b 
where tag='XX' and number=17 and a.id=b.id);
```

Your query won't fetch you any rows because you are trying to select IDs that belong to rows that have Number = 13 and 17 which is not possible. The number can only be 13 or 17.

To match different tags and numbers, you can use "set" as below:

```
set @atag = 'XX', @anumber = 13, @bnumber = 17;

select id from table a where tag=@atag and number=@anumber 
and exists(select id from table b 
where tag=@atag and number=@bnumber and a.id=b.id);
```

o/p:

```
A
```

Comment: But I'll get B too. I want just A Because A have tag XX that have number 13,17 but B have 13,16

Comment: Missed to check your image. Got clarity on your question now. Pls check my edited answer.

Comment: thank you. But If I use "or" I will get "B" That has just tag "XX" with number 13

Comment: thank you very much. But If I have a lot of tag's name and number to match such as tag "XX" with number 13,17 AND tag "YY" with number 12,15 AND tag "ZZ" with number 14,15. Is there a more easy way to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need 2 records as result, so you may try this:

```
SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE Tag="XX" AND Number IN (13, 17)
```

`Tag="XX"` will match 2 rows with Tag "XX".

`Number IN (13, 17)` will match appropriate row which have value 13 or 17.

But in case you need 1 record out of 2 records you have to use `JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT t1.ID FROM Table t1
LEFT JOIN Table t2
  ON t1.Tag="XX" AND t1.Number = 13 AND t2.Tag="XX" AND t2.Number = 17
```

Comment: But I'll get B too. I want just A Because A have tag XX that have number 13,17 but B have 13,16.

Comment: @Sun Updated my answer.

Comment: thank you very much. But If I have a lot of tag's name and number to match such as tag "XX" with number 13,17 AND tag "YY" with number 12,15 AND tag "ZZ" with number 14,15. Is there a more easy way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have number 13 AND number 17. You need to switch your and to an or.

```
SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE ( Tag="XX" and Number = 13 ) OR ( Tag="XX" and Number = 17 )
```